# ffmpeg cut the video and get accurate begining time of the result

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I do the cut via:

```
ffmpeg -i  long_clip.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.0 -c copy -t 00:00:04.0 short_clip.mp4
```

I need to know the precise time where did the ffmpeg do the cut (Time of the closest keyframe before the 00:00:10.0)

Currently, I'm using the following ffprobe command to list all the keyframes and select the closest before 00:00:10.0

```
ffprobe -show_frames -skip_frame nokey long_clip.mp4
```

It works extremely slow (I run It on Jetson Nano, and It is a few minutes to list the keyframes for 30 sec video, although the cutting is done in 0.2seconds)

I hope there is the much faster way to know the time of the keyframe where ffmpeg does the cut, at least because ffmpeg seeks to this keyframe and cuts the video less than in half a second.

**So in other words the question is:** How to get the time of the keyframe where ffmpeg does the cut not listing all the keyframes?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. The most information you can get from a program is obtained when you use the verbosity level of debugging. For `ffmpeg` I just used

```
ffmpeg -v debug -i "Princess Chelsea - Frack.mp4" -ss 00:03:00.600 -c copy -to 00:03:03.800 3.mkv 2> out.txt
```

One has to redirect output, because there is too much of it with *debug*, it doesn't fit the terminal.

Unfortunately, it gives only some cryptic/internal messages, like

> Automatically inserted bitstream filter 'vp9_superframe'; args=''
> [matroska @ 0x55987904cac0] Starting new cluster with timestamp 5 at offset 885 bytes
> [matroska @ 0x55987904cac0] Writing block of size 375 with pts 5, dts 5, duration 23 at relative offset 9 in cluster at offset 885. TrackNumber 2, keyframe 1

With less verbosity it gives less information. Therefore I think this is not possible. However, what is your actual question? Maybe you need something different apart from just knowing the time of cuts?..

For those who look how to actually cut at the proper time (as I was looking for): one has to apply not *copy*, but to actually decode the video anew.